# Using custom jackson serializer to replace an Enum value

Tags: java, json, spring, kotlin, jackson

I'm writing a spring boot project in Kotlin. One of the POJO/data classes I had,

```java
data class Employee(
        //... other properties
        val designation: Designation
)

enum class Designation {
    JUN, MID, SEN
}
```

this `Employee` object by default serializes as `{"designation" : "JUN"}`. I wanted to add a custom serializer so that this object will serialize like this, `{"designation" : "Junior"}`.

The serializer I added,

```java
@JsonComponent
class DesignationSerialization {
    class Serializer: JsonObjectSerializer<Designation>() {
        override fun serializeObject(designation: Designation, gen: JsonGenerator, provider: SerializerProvider) {
            gen.writeString(designation.pretty)
        }

        private val Designation.pretty: String
            get() = when(this) {
                Designation.JUN -> "Junior"
                Designation.MID -> "Mid-Level"
                Designation.SEN -> "Senior"
            }
    }
}
```

But while running this, I am getting this error,

```
JSON encoding error: Can not write a string, expecting field name (context: Object); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a string, expecting field name (context: Object)
```

I also tried using `gen.writeStringField("designation", designation.pretty)` but that serializes the object like this instead

```
{
"designation": {"designation": "Mid-Level"}
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why `@JsonValue` is not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a property to your enum class and mark it with `@JsonValue` https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums